# Java - Casting ArrayList<Object[]> to Object[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, arraylist

Ok, so here's a small problem I'm facing - is there an easy way in Java to cast

```
ArrayList<Object[]> array;
```

to

```
Object[][] data;
```

?

Comment: Why have you called a List "array"?

Comment: @Bohemian It fits naming conventions, and is an *array* List anyway.

Comment: The term "cast" has a specific meaning (well, actually 2 or 3) and there is no way to do what you want with a "cast".  But toArray should work.

Answer (score 6):

```
Object[][] data=array.toArray();
```

The Object[]'s inside are treated as a type of object themselves. They then are put into their own array, leading to an array of array objects of objects, or simply a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is not the solution you are looking for. Casting would essentially allow you to use a method that you cast to a specific class type. An example of a cast:

(((ClassA)classB).method())

So a returned value can be placed inside of a ClassA object from the instantiated classB object that contains method().

What you are wanting to do on the other hand is create a multidimensional array or a 2D array. This is essentially an array of arrays, where arrayA[i] = arrayB[];

For example:

```
Object[] objectArray = new Object[5];
Object[][] = objectArray2D = new Object[][];

objectArray2D[i] = objectArray;
```

Here is a point to your question though, if you create a multidimensional array, why would you feed it only one array instance. Essentially what you would create in the above example is an array inside of an array, and since you will be giving it only 1 array indexing of all the objects inside the array would be the same as if you had the one array, but with one additional placement. Let me explain:

objectArray[0] == the object you placed on the first slot of objectArray

while objectArray2D[0][0] == the exact same object as the object in objectArray[0]

You are not receiving any advantage by using a multidimensional array for one array. If you were to ask the 2D array for the index [1][0] you would receive an out of bounds exception.

Lastly, I would suggest that you create a specific form of array, such as int[], or string[]. The problem with a Object[] array is that you can store anything that is considered an Object into the array, allowing for a potential cluster of different types of Objects inside one array. Example you could have a objectArray[0] = int 1; and objectArray[1] = String one; Unless you want to be very specific in the array use, it might be better to use one Object type as the array.

In any case the final solution to do exactly what you are wanting to do is as follows:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> array;
Object[][] data;

public void changeToAnArray(ArrayList<Object[]> array, Object[][] data)
{
    this.array = array.toArray();
    this.data[0] = array;
}
```

Also due note the point of an ArrayList, is to have a 2D array in essence without having to parse the indexes.

Please anyone feel free to correct on the parts I am wrong on << still learning.